# Cities of Refuge when Moshiach comes?

Tags: death, messiah, city-of-refuge

Why do we need Cities of Refuge when Moshiach comes if at that time there will be no more death?

Comment: Why won't there be any death?

Answer (score 11):

The [Lubavitcher Rebbe answers](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/704632/jewish/More-Refuge-Cities-When-Moshiach-Comes.htm) that we will need the Cities of Refuge for all the people who have killed inadvertently over the course of exile. They will need to go to the city of Refuge to protect themselves from the "blood redeemer" (Go'el Ha-dam). See there for the explanation of why the "blood redeemer" taking revenge is not incompatible with the Days of Moshiach.

[AskMoses.com adds](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/247,2537/Why-will-we-have-Cities-of-Refuge-when-the-Messiah-comes.html) that at the beginning stages of the Messianic Era (see Shaloh mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/city-of-refuge-moshiach/2591#2591)), before the Resurrection of the Dead, the Cohen Gadol can still die, thereby freeing the accidental murderers from the Cities of Refuge.

Answer (score 9):

The **Aruch Laner** answers that natural death will no longer exists but if someone kills someone death will still happen.

The **Chasam Sofer** in **Toras Moshe** on *Parshas Shoftim* says that maybe you can answer that the *Geirim*  (proselytes)  that come to Klal Yisroel  will not reach the level of death not affecting them, but will be  only counted as Jews and therefore the Cities of refuge will be for them.

The **Shnei Luchos Habris** known to us by his acronym as the **Shlah** answers there are many different time periods after Moshiach comes, the city of refuge will be needed for the initial stages and only later will death disappear from the world.

The **Meshech Chachmah** answers that there are two ways Moshiach can come we bring him with our good deeds or time runs out and history runs its course and Hashem is forced to bring Moshiach even though we are undeserving. In the case we are undeserving the outcome will be as the Rambam says the World will continue as it is accustomed and Death will still happen and that is why the city of refuge will be needed if  we get Moshiach by History runing its course.

Comment: Sources? [15 characters]

Answer (score 6):

As always, the simple answer is according to the Rambam, the times of Moshiach will have death too.

R' Aryeh Kaplan thus paskens (if I can use the term) that Moshiach (yes even ben Dovid) will die, too.

Comment: how do you address bilah hamaves lanetach?

Comment: I mean how does the Rambam i am guessing it is in the Moreh somwhere?

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's the non-physical existence that comes AFTER Yemos HaMoshiach.  (Someone please correct me if I'm getting the Rambam wrong.)

Comment: Rambam says moshiach will die and his son will take over (In the Yad)

Comment: Abarbanel, who follows Rambam's opinion, gives two possible explanations for "bilah hamaves lanetzach":
1) Emphasis on "lanetzach". The fact that death lasts forever will be destroyed come techiyas hamesim time. So don't read "death will be destroyed forever", but rather "Death forever will be destroyed".
2) "Maves" refers to the hard times of galus. The geulah will destroy the "maves" of galus.

Comment: Where does Rambam write this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming included in your question is why is there a command to add three cities of refuge when Moshiach comes ([Deuteronomy 19:8 with Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.19.8?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.19.9.1)). If so, [Rav Daniel Glatstein](https://www.rabbidg.com/) dedicated [an entire *shiur* to this question](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=159408) (starting 15:30), and came up with **eight reasons** (some of which are in the other answers). Even if I'm wrong in understanding your question, these answers still address your question as written.

1. When Moshiach comes there will be no more wars (and murderers), however that doesn't mean that there won't still be accidental deaths ([**Be'er BaSadeh** to Deuteronomy 19:8](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22552&st=&pgnum=345); [**Aruch LaNer**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14412&st=&pgnum=32) (Makkos 9b *s.v.* בגלעד), as SimchasTorah brought).
2. We won't need them, even though we must establish and continue to have them. It's simply a *gezeiras hakasuv*, a decree of the Writ ([**Minchas Chinuch** § 520](https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Chinukh.520)).
3. Those who killed these days by accident will need to go to exile when Moshiach comes ([**Yedei Moshe** to Devarim Rabbah 4:30](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=200321&pagenum=51); as Menachem answered in the name of the **Lubavitcher Rebbe** (if you see the article he linked to, the source the Lubavitcher Rebbe is coming from is the [**Alshich**](https://www.sefaria.org/Alshich_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.19.8.1?lang=bi)); Rav Glatstein didn't reference this but I found the **Chida** in his [**Penei Dovid**](https://www.sefaria.org/Penei_David%2C_Deuteronomy%2C_Shoftim.11.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) (Shoftim § 11) says this in the name of the **Sheivet Mussar**).
4. When Moshiach comes, everyone will miraculously become good, so no one will die. However, we aren't supposed to rely on miracles, and therefore we have  to separate the cities of refuge as if there won't be a miraculous existence (Rav Glatstein didn't say who he was quoting).
5. All the prophecies about the supernatural nature of Moshiach are for the Jewish people. All those who will want to convert to Judaism at that time will not be subject to that miraculous existence, and will still be able to accidentally kill ([**Maskil LeDovid** to Deuteronomy 19:8](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19148&st=&pgnum=321); **Chasam Sofer** in [Toras Moshe to Deuteronomy 19:8](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21814&st=&pgnum=74), as SimchasTorah brought). **Rav Chaim Kanivesky** says somewhat similarly in his [Nachal Eisan 1:1:6](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/106396/p/16/t/0586215991234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c), that non-Jews in the land of Israel (who have the status of *ger toshav*) will still accidentally kill each other, and the *gemarra* says that a *ger toshav* that kills a *ger toshav* goes to exile (Makkos 8b). He also brings this in his Ta'amah D'Kra to Deuteronomy 19:8.
6. Chazal say that *Ba'alei Teshuva* are on a higher level than those who never sinned. As such, those that never sinned will need the cities of refuge, unlike the *Ba'alei Teshuva* of the end of days (**Chasam Sofer Al HaTorah** to Deuteronomy 19:8).
7. As the process of Moshiach unfolds and the land of Israel is expanded to include the entire world, there will still be a natural order of things in which the cities of refuge will be necessary ([**Shlah HaKadosh**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45685&st=&pgnum=53) (*Hakdamas Toldos HaAdam Beis Dovid*), as SimchasTorah brought).
8. If Moshiach comes at his designated time, there won't be a need for the cities of refuge. However, the verse is referring to a scenario where Moshiach is bought early, for Kabbalistic reasons there will be a need for the cities of refuge, or explained simply the world won't be changed to a supernatural state but rather continue as it does now. This is why the verse is written "if Hashem expands your borders", and not "when Hashem expands your borders". (**Arizal** ([Lukkutei Torah *parshas Shoftim*](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30734&st=&pgnum=181), brought by [**Shlah HaKadosh**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45685&st=&pgnum=54) (*ibid*), brought by [**Maskil LeDovid**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19148&st=&pgnum=321) (*ibid*); [**Meshech Chochmah**](https://www.sefaria.org/Meshekh_Chokhmah%2C_Shoftim.49?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) to Deuteronomy 19:8, as brought by SimchasTorah, although if you see he says the opposite of how SimchasTorah described it, and instead like the Arizal; see also the above **Alshich**, who seems to borrow part of this interpretation from the Arizal).