# What happens to Converts and Chalalim once the Moshiach comes?

Tags: kohen-priest, messiah, shevatim-12-tribes

As per the answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43825/status-of-owned-land-after-moshiach-comes), there is a general consensus that when Moshiach comes, we will find out who belongs to what tribe, and the 12 tribes will revert to their original landholdings. We see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/cities-of-refuge-when-moshiach-comes) that the Levites will reclaim the cities of refuge. With a rebuilt Beit HaMikdash, the Cohanim and some Levites would presumably return to Temple service. So far so good.

What, though, happens to Chalalim? They are obviously possul for service in the Beit Hamikdash, and are not considered Levites such that they could be eligible for homes in the Cities of Refuge. Yet they do not belong to any tribe that has landholdings.

Similarly, we currently classify converts (or at least their children) as "Yisrael", but that will no longer be an option.

Are there any sources that speak of these two groups in the messianic era?

Comment: Wouldn't chalalim inherit from their kohen ancestors?

Comment: @Heshy kohenim don't really own property per se (I mean, they can, but it's not part of "the system"), rather, they get Teruma, tithes and jobs at the Beit HaMikdash in lieu of, say, productive farmland. None of these are available to a chalal as a source of income

Comment: I mean their land in the Levi cities.  As far as I know, the normal inheritance rules apply to them, and the only difference from normal land is the rules in Bechukosai about how it gets sold.

Comment: "are not considered Levites such that they could be eligible for homes in the Cities of Refuge" is the major claim your question is premise on, so supporting it would strengthen your question. I've never heard of such a thing, personally.

Comment: Why would you assume the law would be any different than before the Exile?

Comment: how do you know that just b/c chalalim are posul from serving in the bes hamikdash that means they will not be eligible to have homes?

Comment: Excellent question, @Dude. For most things, a *chalal* has the din of Yisrael. And his son, in fact is outright Yisrael. Everyone else will revert to their tribal affiliation and landholdings when Moshiach comes (a random guy at shul doesn't have any awareness his forefathers were part of, say, Yissachar though he is in fact a Yissacharite), but a *chalal* is *no longer a Kohain or even a Levite*. So where can he go?

Answer (score 3):

As far as gerim, see [Yechezkel 47:22-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.47.22):

> וְהָיָ֗ה תַּפִּ֣לוּ אוֹתָהּ֮ בְּנַחֲלָה֒ לָכֶ֗ם וּלְהַגֵּרִים֙ הַגָּרִ֣ים בְּתוֹכְכֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁר־הוֹלִ֥דוּ בָנִ֖ים בְּתֽוֹכְכֶ֑ם וְהָי֣וּ לָכֶ֗ם כְּאֶזְרָח֙ בִּבְנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אִתְּכֶם֙ יִפְּל֣וּ בְנַחֲלָ֔ה בְּת֖וֹךְ שִׁבְטֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל: וְהָיָ֣ה בַשֵּׁ֔בֶט אֲשֶׁר־גָּ֥ר הַגֵּ֖ר אִתּ֑וֹ שָׁ֚ם תִּתְּנ֣וּ נַחֲלָת֔וֹ
>
> You shall allot it as a heritage for yourselves and for the strangers who reside among you, who have begotten children among you. You shall treat them as Israelite citizens; they shall receive allotments along with you among the tribes of Israel. You shall give the stranger an allotment within the tribe where he resides...

The commentaries there take this at face value, and Abarbanel, in particular, says that it's only fair: since these gerim suffered the pains of galus together with the born Jews, they ought to share in their rewards too. (Although Sifri, cited and commented on in [Torah Temimah to Bamidbar 10:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.10.29.2?lang=he), says that they'll be entitled only to land for burial plots.)

Comment: That certainly settles the matter as far as Gerim are concerned! Thanks.